# Asking questions about Ebooks copyrights

Tags: discussion

Is it suitable to ask questions about Ebooks copyrights, legitimacy of hosting ebook torrent files, magnet links; or hosting ebook webpages with covers and metadata, all preceding options with or without ads for income, on Law StackExchange?

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably on-topic. The best way to find out is to post your question.